# SIP encryption and Compression, best approach

Tags: performance, encryption, cryptography, compression, sip

What is the best way to do the below items with SIP without call quality degradation:

1. Voice encryption (Many people suggest using TLS, but I think it will degrade the call quality, specially when doing conference calls with multiple parties involved).
2. Voice compression (is it all about using the proper encoder, or we can take it one step further?)

Comment: Very close to off topic. Look at http://security.stackexchange.com if you want to ask security related questions that don't directly involve programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption depends on capability of all parties to support certain standard. If you use communication over UDP, you would need to use DTLS (Datagram-based flavor of SSL/TLS), but support for DTLS is not widespread (though both OpenSSL and our SecureBlackbox support it). Effect on performance in case of voice communication will be minimal (voice doesn't take much bandwidth).

Compressing traffic doesn't make much sense if you use some voice code which already supports compression. The benefit of double-compressing the stream will be minimal, and extra load on processor (especially in case of mobile devices) will be more significant.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The point is, the use of public/private keys encryption strategy might be a pain, talking about a system that can handle hundreds of thousands of calls a day. Also how about the other options for encryption, like: AES, ZRTP, SRTP?

Comment: @securecurve TLS/DTLS doesn't require PKI - it has alternative authentication mechanisms including PSK (pre-shared keys), which is the same as using symmetric encryption. With low-level approaches (eg. AES encryption) you will have to exchange keys somehow, and thus reinvent and reimplement the things already present in TLS (key exchange, integrity control etc.). I have no experience with SRTP and ZRTP, but given that they are not mentioned widely, I guess one will have hard time finding libraries to implement them.